# What is a good way in maven/surefire to clean up after unit tests, whether they pass or not?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, surefire

We have some unit tests that unfortunately create memory-mapped NIO files that cannot be deleted by the process that created them (some windows issue).

Regardless, I would like to run some sort of clean up after these tests, whether they passed or not.  I was going to run a small ant script at the *prepare-package* phase, but if any test fails, surefire exits immediately.

Apart from going to the **failsafe** plugin which has a post-test phase, is there any clever way I can run my cleanup regardless of pass or fail?

I suspect not - I've gone through all the **surefire** config options...

edit:  memory-mapped nio files [cannot](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4715154) be deleted in the same process, even by deleteOnExit.

Comment: maybe use a VM - and simply reset it.

Comment: if you don't care that the files are lying around, you could delete them **before** the tests, e.g. in the `process-test-resources` build phase

Comment: Are you *sure* they can't be deleted? Have you tried `java.io.File.deleteOnExit()`?

Comment: @artbristol - yeah, deleteOnExit does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bound the thing you want to do into the post-integration-test lifecycle phase which is running afterwards the integration-test phase which is handled by the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/). It might work if you configure the maven-clean-plugin to do so.

Comment: if surefire fails on a test, it doesn't seem to fire off any more phases.  It just forces maven to exit.

Comment: Of course, cause failing tests is an indication that's something wrong which needs to be fixed first before continuing. You can use mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true (but i don't recommend that).

Comment: @marathon Failsafe is designed so that even if the tests fail, the `post-integration-test` phase still runs and does any cleanup

Comment: @artbristol that's supposed to be the case, but I haven't seen a good sample pom file that demonstrates it along with how everything needs to be configured.  I'm having a somewhat similar problem as marathon and I'm sure it's a configuration problem, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  But marathon wants to try to do it without failsafe, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure the files are created in either `target/` or the OS's temporary directory (using `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`. Then they will be cleaned up automatically when you run `mvn clean`, or eventually by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependancy in pom and remove existing from your POM

```
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```